# CDA Broker API : Get ComponentPresentations by list of component IDs

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I am trying to see if there is a way to get the ComponentPresentations by passing the list of ComponentIDs in one single API instead of passing each one in a loop. In my case all the DCPs are using the same template as well.

When I checked the API I could not find any method which could accept the list of tcmids or something in those lines. The use case I am trying to solve is getting all the DCPs in one single API call vs. looping through 10-15 (in my case) and get each DCP independently which is not effective when the first time we hit the broker db.

I was able to get the same using OData web service, but we not yet ready to use the Odata. Not sure if Odata and broker API are slightly different, but could not find any documentation that explain API vs Odata difference in capabilities from query point.

Any help will be appreciated.

ENV: Tridion 2011 SP1, Java API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OData and Broker API are *very* different. If you want information on OData I'd recommend checking [here](http://www.odata.org/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odata).

No, you can't do that operation through the Content Delivery API. With a properly configured cache you will be hitting the database only once per component presentation, so the impact is minimized...

Comment: Yeah, we do have cache but some optimization we are trying to enhance better but if API does not support then we will live with the way we have today. On separate note, I am looking for more of comparison type of doc between Odata and API in terms of broker query type functionality of what you can do with API and what you cannot and same for Odata as well. At the moment, it is not very clear from the docs.. probably there isn't one.. Anyway thank you for the response.

Comment: No, that document doesn't exist. OData is a different way of working with data, really focused on Collections rather than individual items - the API focuses (too much perhaps) on individual objects